# Access NuGet package in a different GitHub repository

Tags: github, .net-core, nuget, repository, nuget-package

I have repo A and repo B that are part of the same organization on GitHub. Both repositories are private. I published two NuGet packages to repo A and one package to repo B.

repo A can install its own packages without a problem, but it does not have access to repo B's package. I'm getting the following error when I run `dotnet build`:

> error NU1101: Unable to find package {{PackageId}}. No packages exist
> with this id in source(s): github. PackageSourceMapping is enabled,
> the following source(s) were not considered:
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/library-packs, nuget.org.

My `nuget.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/{{orgname}}/index.json" />
    </packageSources>

    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="{{USERNAME}}" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{{TOKEN}}" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>

    <packageSourceMapping>
        <packageSource key="github">
            <package pattern="{{OrgName}}.*" />
        </packageSource>

        <packageSource key="nuget.org">
            <package pattern="*" />
        </packageSource>
    </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

PAT has `repo` and `write:packages` permissions with no expiration. How can repo A access packages pushed under repo B?

NOTE: Changing the package's visibility to `internal` does not work.

Comment: You mentioned a PAT, so the answer might be yes, but have you read github's docs? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#considering-cross-repository-access

Comment: I'm testing multi-repo packages locally at the moment (i.e. no GitHub Actions). The current (classic) PAT is at user level for a user who has admin access. Reading that article gave me the idea to create a fine-grained PAT at org level, but this made no difference when I executed `dotnet build` after modifying `nuget.config` by changing username and password fields.

Comment: @user246392 What is the [scope](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) of your PAT? It should have `read:packages` scope along with `repo` and `write:packages`. I see the one you are using misses `read:packages`?

Comment: `write:packages` automatically includes `read:packages` which is nested under `write:packages`. So, when I select write scope, read scope is selected automatically on the UI without the ability to unselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable repo A to access packages published in repo B, even when both are private repositories within the same GitHub organization, follow the following:

1. **Confirm Package Visibility**:  Make sure that the packages in repo B are correctly published as NuGet packages and have the necessary permissions in place.
2. **Check GitHub Token Permissions**: Verify that the GitHub token ({{TOKEN}}) used in your nuget.config file has the required permissions:

   - **read:packages**
   - **write:packages**
   - **delete:packages**
3. **Review NuGet Configurations**: Carefully validate the placeholders ({{orgname}} and {{USERNAME}}) in your nuget.config file, ensuring they match your GitHub organization's details.
4. **Confirm Repository Names**: Double-check that package references in repo A correctly match the package name in repo B, including the organization name.
5. **Add Package Source** : Explicitly include the package source for repo B in your nuget.config file, and specify this source when installing packages from repo B.
6. **Clear NuGet Cache**:

   ```
   dotnet nuget locals all --clear
   ```
7. **Validate Repository Permissions** : Ensure that GitHub repository permissions for both repo A and repo B are properly configured to allow access to packages within your organization.
8. **Test with a Different Token** : If issues persist, generate a new GitHub token with the necessary permissions and update your nuget.config to use the new token. This can help rule out token-related issues.